# HyperV Edit hard disk is not available because of checkpoints

Tags: hyper-v

I am trying to increase the size of my hard drive in a VM. I disabled checkpoints and deleted all existing checkpoints. However, it still will not let me. I also restarted and then shut down the VM after removing all the checkpoints in case that was it.

[image]

Comment: Is the avhd a differencing disk or checkpoint?

Comment: @GregAskew I don't know. How do I find out? And if it's the wrong kind, how do I convert? TIA

Comment: @GregAskew I did have checkpoints, but I deleted them all to resize the disk. And I rebooted after doing so. So should that mean the avhd can NOT be a checkpoint?

Comment: A normal disk is vhd/vhdx. An avhd may be a checkpoint, but could also be a differencing disk.

Comment: @GregAskew It's a .vhd file

Comment: The screen shot shows an avhd file.

Comment: @GregAskew Ok this is weird, I didn't fully look at it after rebooting the host machine. It now is a .vhd file. And it's now editable. I think the answer was reboot the host machine, then run and exit the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed on Windows 11 Hyper-V Version: 10.0.19041.1 following steps:

1. shutdown VM, click "checkpoint" (6th line below setup), checkpoints will show up in middle screen, right click to delete each line
2. in setup disable checkpoint
3. start and shutdown VM, double check under VM disk folder you will find all *.avhdx are removed
4. edit VM disk, expand its size, restart VM.

I use non-fixed size VM disk. The default size of 127 GB is useless and not helpful.

Comment: how does this answer the question at all?

Comment: @djdomi I followed these steps and I was able to edit the disk.   I think the main thing is after deleting the check points the VM had to be restarted and shut down again.

Answer (score 0):

Shut down the VM.
Sometimes it's the only way to force snapshots to coalesce.

Answer (score 0):

OP's solution did not work for me.  I had deleted all checkpoints, and even started the VM successfully, but then it began crashing on start with this in the Hyper-V-VMMS event viewer log (even after host reboot):

*'MyVMName' background disk merge failed to complete: The chain of virtual hard disks is corrupted. There is a mismatch in the identifiers of the parent virtual hard disk and differencing disk.*

The reason for this is because Hyper-V had (apparently) thought I deleted all checkpoints, but on disk, there still remained one (a .avhdx file in addition to a .vhdx file).
The solution is this powershell command:

`Set-VHD “D:\MyVMPath\some_guid.avhdx” –ParentPath “D:\MyVMPath\MyVMName.vhdx” -ignoreidmismatch`

Comment: You have to wait after deleting the checkpoints for it to finish merging the differences to the main file.